# WebApi and Routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue where my POST is not being hit on the web server.  It is going into the constructor of my controller but not going into the post method I have set up.

This is the route I have set up

```
routes.MapScopedHttpRoute(
    name: "AliasesApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/aliases/{controller}/{id}",
    @namespace: "Test.WebApi.Aliases",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

This is the controller

```
public IResponseModel Post(AliasTreeItem node)
{
    ...
}
```

The URL being called is below and it is definatley a POST

```
http://localhost:61265/api/aliases/alias?_dc=1439962373744
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this?

I have my Get method being hit just not this Post method.

Answer (score 0):

but your post have a parameter called node, and in the url you have a parameter _dc (the name needs to be the same), the parameter name is different, also, node is the type AliasTreeItem, that I think is a class, so is better send the data into the body of the request.

Also, to test I recommended to use postman or fiddler.

Comment: The _dc is tagged onto the URL by the framework we are using.  I think it is for caching but not 100% sure.  Either way that data is not something we use on the server side.  The data is actually being posted in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `[FromBody]` attribute to your controller action, like this:

```
public IResponseModel Post([FromBody]AliasTreeItem node)
{
    ...
}
```

This will tell *WebApi* that the route is expecting a POST request with `AliasTeamItem` in the body. Even if you don't send anything in the body this will work, as empty body content for your reference type will be null.

Answer (score 0):

So just to round this one out.  I was using route attributes on the GET methods as I had two GET requests.  I only had one PUT request so I didn't add a route request on that method.  Turns out I need that method.  My 3 methods are below and now it all seems to be working normally.

```
        // GET /api/aliases/alias
        [Route(Order = 1)]
        public IResponseModel Get(string id)

        // GET /api/aliases/alias/simple
        [Route("simple", Order = 2)]
        public IResponseModel GetSimple(int page, int start, int limit, string query = null)

        // POST /api/aliases/alias
        [Route(Order = 3)]
        public IResponseModel Post([FromBody]AliasTreeItem node)
```